# Chrome can't download jQuery, other browsers can

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

For some reason Chrome on my computer absolutely refuses to download this file:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

When I try, I get this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Firefox downloads it right away. I've tried deleting all cookies, disabling all extensions, running in incognito mode, and even rebooting my whole computer. I've also confirmed that my hosts file doesn't have anything strange in it.

I'm running the latest version of Chrome (36.0.1985.125 m) on Windows 7 x64.

What might cause this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall/proxy? Have you tried HTTPS?

Comment: Are you just clicking on the link or are you right-clicking and selecting "save link as..."?

Comment: please post your solution as an answer, not in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

> Uninstalled and re-installed Chrome, and that seems to have fixed the
>   issue.

- [self answer](https://superuser.com/posts/787132/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

Temporary, you can use another CDN url

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Are you use any ad blocker?